# PHP Array (list) to Table

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array as below

```
$x= array("Name","Age","Place","John",34,"London","Ram",12,"New Delhi");
```

here I've to get as below

```
Name    Age     Place
John    34      London
Ram     12      New Delhi
```

is there any option to do this?

Comment: you need to show data in table?

Comment: Yes, or in JSON format.

Comment: Then just use `json_encode` is you want a json.

Comment: Your only option is to write some code

Comment: PS That is a very unhelpful array you have built. It is useless unless you know how many occurances make up a relevant record

Comment: Actually it is extracted from a webpage, thats why its looks like that.
when i use json encode its still as same patern, right?

Comment: Do you know how many column are in your array? (in your example - 3)

Comment: ya, Column is fixed to 8 in my real case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the number of column you can use [array-chunk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) :

```
$x= array("Name","Age","Place","John",34,"London","Ram",12,"New Delhi");
foreach(array_chunk($x, 3) as $row) // 3 is the number of column
    echo implode("\t", $row) . PHP_EOL;
```

This will generate the output as:

```
Name    Age     Place
John    34      London
Ram     12      New Delhi
```